# Set System.setOut to default console AND a custom output

Tags: java, string, methods, console, output

I have a piece of code like this:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream()
{

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException
    {
        String str = String.valueOf((char) b);
        txtAreaConsole.appendText(str);
    }
}));
```

But that means, I don't get any information in the console anymore.
So I'm looking for something like this:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream()
{

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException
    {
        String str = String.valueOf((char) b);
        txtAreaConsole.appendText(str);
        defaultConsole.appendText(str); //THIS
    }
}));
```

Is there anything like that? Thanks

Comment: You can use [`TeeOutputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html) from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), or just write it yourself like you already started doing.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TeeOutputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html) from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io) was, as Andreas suggested, the best way for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, you just need to "save" and reuse the existing System.out.

I don't know what txtAreaConsole is in you code, so I just made a "MyConsole" in the following example:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.text.*;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        System.setOut(new MySystemOut(System.out, new MyConsole()));
        System.out.println("Hey");
    }

    class MyConsole {

        public void appendText(String s) {
            // write text somewhere else here
        }
    }

    class MySystemOut extends PrintStream {

        private final PrintStream out;
        private final MyConsole txtAreaConsole;

        public MySystemOut(PrintStream out, MyConsole txtAreaConsole) {
            super(out);
            this.out = out;
            this.txtAreaConsole = txtAreaConsole;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) {
            String str = String.valueOf((char) b);
            txtAreaConsole.appendText(str);
            out.write(b);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        new Test();
    }
}
```